# CloudKit and CoreData Default Values

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit, xcode11

I'm setting up core data using an `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` so that my data will automatically have CloudKit integration. The problem I'm having is that I can no longer have optional attributes in my entities. All of my optional attributes generate a compiler error

> [entity].[attribute] must have a default value

Is this a bug? Is there a good work around for this issue?

Comment: I also don't know if it's a bug or a feature. But I guess that right now it's simply one of the limitations that come with CoreData's auto sync (apart from the ones apple mentions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/creating_a_core_data_model_for_cloudkit). Maybe the default values are required to initialize the CloudKit schema. A good work around, well, is to provide default values. ;)

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I added default values, for all except the Integers, left them at 0, note when you tap on a attribute the attribute inspector does not show you where to type the default value, you have to double click on the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be fixed in Xcode 11 beta 3.

Comment: I have the same issue with xCode 11.0 beta 6. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Xcode 14.1 still has this issue

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" is just to make all links optional. On the XCode 11 GM this is still the same, don't think its "fixed" in any xcode beta.

I think the reason is that the way it syncs to CloudKit, they want to have full control of syncing by entity types, hence there might be short period of time where the link are broken.